# tensorflow control dependency

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics

I'm trying to run a very simple example of code that I found online:

```py
    with graph.as_default():
        with sess.as_default():

            labels = tf.constant([[[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]]])
            predictions = tf.constant([[[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]]])

            t = 0.5
            y_pred_ = tf.to_int32(predictions > t)
            score, up_opt = tf.metrics.mean_iou(labels, y_pred_, 3)
            with tf.control_dependencies([up_opt]):
                score_2 = 1.0 * score
            sess.run([tf.local_variables_initializer()])
            result = sess.run([score_2])
```

This is supposed to give me the mean iou of this dummy example. However, if I run this multiple times, I get different results. I've noticed that running `up_opt` manually fixes it:

```py
    with graph.as_default():
        with sess.as_default():

            labels = tf.constant([[[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]]])
            predictions = tf.constant([[[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]]])

            t = 0.5
            y_pred_ = tf.to_int32(predictions > t)
            score, up_opt = tf.metrics.mean_iou(labels, y_pred_, 3)
            sess.run([tf.local_variables_initializer()])
            sess.run([up_opt])
            result = sess.run([score])
```

However, I wonder why the control_dependencies doesn't work. Isn't this supposed to run the operators automatically?

Comment: In the second code snippet, `score_2` is not defined. Did you mean to add `score_2 = 1.0 * score` there without the `with` statement? Are you using TF 1.15?

Comment: It was a typo. I intended `sess.run([score])`. I updated my question. I'm using tensorflow 1.14